# Split a String by another string

Tags: java, string, split, emoticons

I'm wondering about how I can do something like this:

```
String[] emoticon;
emoticon=e.split(":)");
```

Is it possible to be done with split(); or is there another way around?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. The split method can split one string by another. But see the comments below for a discussion on escape characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to use the smiley face `:)` as a delimiter, there is a consideration you have to make: `split()` accepts regex, so you have to escape (with `\\`) any [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) you use (including but not limited to `()[]+*`):

```
emoticon=e.split(":\\)");
```

[**Proof-of-concept on IDEOne**](http://ideone.com/Oc8M87)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Pattern.quote`:

```
emoticon = e.split(Pattern.quote(":)"));
```

It will surround your `String` with `\Q` and `\E` and escape any `\E` substrings within your pattern.

Comment: Alternatively you can just use Pattern.quote("whatever string you want to split by"), and it will return an already escaped string for you.

Comment: I actually discovered that function just as you wrote that comment. Spooky.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape the braces:

```
emoticon=e.split(":\\)");
```

but you know, this will get rid of the emoticon, right?

to retrieve it out of some text you'll need something like this:

```
List<String> emoticons = new ArrayList<String>();
// adjust regex to find more emoticons
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    emoticons.add(matcher.group());
}
```